# Excel Macro and "PERSONAL" File

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, excel-2003, vba

So when ever I open a Excel sheet (2003-2007-2010) it runs a macro and opens a blank excel doc named "PERSONAL." How do I stop it from opening the "PERSONAL" excel file.

---

---

[image]

Comment: Ask Linda to release to lock, or complain to the IT-department for customizing excel this way.

Comment: Solved: Click Read Only--> View --> Hide --> Save

Comment: @MichaelDowney: you can answer your own question and accept the answer. This will then "close" the topic and help further reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

press alt-F11 to open the VBA editor from within Excel. Once you're inside press ctrl-F to open the "find" dialog window. Select the "Current Project" radio button to search all modules and VBA objects for "PERSONAL.xls". Keep pressing "Find Next" until you find the line of code that looks like it opens it. You could delete it, but it is probably there for a reason so it may be better to follow amadeus suggestion...

Answer (score 2):

This probably happens when you open a second instance of Excel. Normally the first instance opens your PERSONAL.XLS, the file where all your personal macro's are stored. If you open other files inside this first instance, then there is no problem. When you launch a second instance of Excel, the second instance can't get write rights to the file PERSONAL as this file is in use by the first instance.

Regards,

Robert Ilbrink